# Reverse engineer the update-binary file in Android recovery update packages

Tags: android, mips, decompile

I am trying to understand how to disassemble or at least get a readable copy of the update-binary file located in /META-INF/com/google/android/. It is a modified version for a smartwatch, which contains the key used by the manufacturer to temporarily unlock the bootloader and let the system update properly. I searched on the net but I did not find anything related to this.
Have you got any idea of how could I extract that key form the binary file? The architecture is MIPS.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: what is the name of the file? Does it have any discernible structure? does the dex code reference it in any way?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a MIPS ELF binary. Maybe you can use [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) (Win/Linux) or [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com/) (Mac/Linux) or [JEB](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/jeb2/mips) (Win/Mac/Linux) to poke around.  If you have a clue about the length or parts of the key, then you could try to search for relevant strings.

I've never tried it myself (MIPS), but maybe the approach helps you. ;)
Cheers!